git status --porcelain return file difference that are identical
I want to create a workflow that would ensures that the PR owner executed npm install && gulp compile-assets before submitting that PR. So I added a Github workflow that runs and does the following steps

Checkout the branch
runs npm install && gulp compile-assets
Then runs git status --porcelain to see if there are any differences. The expectation here is to have no changes since all changes done by npm install && gulp compile-assets locally should have been committed.

However, the git status --porcelain seems to always returns difference. When I apply `git diff committed-file generated-file
I see there is no change at all. The diff shows @@ -1,21 +1,21 @@ and nothing was changed. But the diff shows that all the lines were removed and added "but the outcome is identical"
I tried adding git config core.autocrlf false && git config core.filemode true before git status --porcelain but did not change the outcome.
What could be causing git status --porcelain to show file difference without any true change?
Here is a screenshot that shows part of file that show diff, but there is no change made.
The project has a .gitattributes file with the following
* text=auto

**/package.json text eol=lf
**/package-lock.json text eol=lf



Did the line endings change before and after?

No. The project has a .gitattribute file. I updated the OP to show the content of the file.

There is definitely a change in the output.  On the left, line 14 contains "devDependencies": {, and on the right, that's line 15.
It's likely that something is formatting these files in a certain way using a tidy tool.  If that's a tool you've configured, great, then make sure that the tool has an appropriate configuration file so users can call it from their editor or the command line.  If it's another tool making unwanted changes, then figure out how to disable that functionality.
The difference could also be primarily in the amount or type of whitespace; for example, tabs instead of spaces, or different amounts of indentation, or different line endings.  Any of these can cause differences in output for every line.  Running cat -v on the file before and after or using a tool like od -tx1 or xxd -g1 can help you figure out what the actual bytes are in the file and therefore what the relevant difference is.

Thank you! I still can't tell what could be the difference. I am running the same command locally and it does not create new file that are any different. The only different is that my local machine is Windows while the workflow is running on linux.

I manually deleted the package-lock.json file from my project. Then manually opened and saved the package.json file.
Finally, executed npm update && gulp compile-assets when all worked.

Something to do with EOLs?
